# SQLException while invoking MobileFirst SQLAdapter

Tags: db2, sqlexception, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am getting this error:

> FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project ***]com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.66.46 java.lang.RuntimeException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.66.46.
>   Performed query:
>   update account set regTstamp = (current timestamp) where accountId = ?

while invoking the SQLAdapter.
Here is the invoke procedure:

```
var AcceptTocInvokeData = {
    adapter : 'DataAdapter',
    procedure : 'updateAcceptTocDate',
    params: [accountId]
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(AcceptTocInvokeData, {
    onSuccess: function(resp) {
        deferred.resolve(resp);
    },
    onFailure: function(resp) {
        deferred.reject(resp);
    }
});
```

and the SQLAdapter code:

```
var prepStmt = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("update account set regTstamp = (current timestamp) where accountId = ?");

function updateAcceptTocDate(accountId) {       
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement: prepStmt,
        parameters: [accountId]
    });
}
```

If I call the adapter from MobileFirst Studio (Run as...), it works perfectly.
Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: What error are you getting in the client-side, for example what do you see in the Chrome devtools?

Comment: Nearly the same errormessage: `Procedure invocation error. Runtime: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.66.46.
Performed query:
update account set regTstamp = (current timestamp) where accountId = ?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution on my own:
I wrote in the invokeData `params` not `parameters`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the DB2 manual for `SQLCODE -313`, you might see something like this:

> The number of variables in the EXECUTE statement, the number of variables in the OPEN statement, or the number of arguments in an OPEN statement for a parameterized cursor is not equal to the number of values required.

Apparently, the parameter is not bound to the prepared statement.